# Angular 2 JS dropdown, select item from another component

Tags: select, drop-down-menu, angular

I have two components one is **employee** and another is **department**. I want to make a dropdown so that **employee** can select a **department**.

I implemented a method for getting all departments inside my employee component:

```
getAllDepartment(){
  this._employeeService.getAllDepartment()
 .subscribe(data => this.departments = data.json());
}
```

in my employee html select looks like this:

```
<label for="editTitle">Department:</label><br>
  <select  [(ngModel)]="newItem.Department" (click)="getAll()" style="width: 180px">
  <option *ngFor="#department of departments" [value]="department.departmentNo">{{department.departmentName}}</option>
  </select>
```

but noting happens.
What is the best way for make this dropdown work and select items?
This is ahtml where I have select:

```
  <form  #f="ngForm" [hidden]="!showAddView" align="center">
        <div>
            <label for="editTitle">Employee No:</label><br>
             <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="newItem.employeeNo" ngControl="employeeNo" required >    

        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="editAbrv">Employee name:</label><br>
              <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="newItem.employeeName" ngControl="demployeeName" required >    
        </div>

            <div>
            <label for="editTitle">Department:</label><br>
            <select [(ngModel)]="newItem.departmentNo" (click)="getAll()" style="width: 180px">
               <option *ngFor="#department of departments" [value]="department.departmentNo">{{department.departmentName}}</option>
           </select>
        </div>

        <div>
            <label for="editAbrv">Salary:</label><br>
             <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="newItem.salary" ngControl="salary" required>    
        </div>

        <div>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" (click)="addEmployee(newItem)" title="Add">
                Save
            </a>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" (click)="showHide($event)" >
                Cancel
            </a>
        </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are binding the click event of the select box to a `getAll()` method, but the method that you have defined is called `getAllDepartment()`.

You need to bind the event to an existing method name.

That being said, I'm unsure why you would want to reload the departments every time the dropdown is clicked.  If the desired behaviour is to load the departments once when the component is initialized, you should add a `constructor()` method to the component, which will be called automatically.

```
constructor() {
    this._employeeService.getAllDepartment()
        .subscribe(data => this.departments = data.json());
}
```

Comment: But, I have a problem, when I select something from dropdown, item isn't selected (I can see it on table).

Comment: I'm unclear on the problem.  Create another question with the specifics.